# Transform dataframe column headers to row entries in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

year = [2005, 2006, 2007]
A = [4, 5, 7]
B = [3, 3, 9]
C = [1, 7, 6]
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'year' : year, 'A' : A, 'B' : B, 'C' : C})

Out[25]: 
   A  B  C  year
0  4  3  1  2005
1  5  3  7  2006
2  7  9  6  2007
```

I want to transform this to a new dataframe where the column headers ´A´, ´B´ and ´C´ are in the rows. I have this hack, which sorta does the job

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'year' : list(df_old['year']) + list(df_old['year'])\
                       + list(df_old['year']),
                       'col' : ['A']*len(df_old['A']) + ['B']*len(df_old['B'])\
                       + ['C']*len(df_old['C']),
                       'val' : list(df_old['A']) + list(df_old['B'])\
                       + list(df_old['C'])})

Out[27]: 
  col  val  year
0   A    4  2005
1   A    5  2006
2   A    7  2007
3   B    3  2005
4   B    3  2006
5   B    9  2007
6   C    1  2005
7   C    7  2006
8   C    6  2007
```

Is there a better, more compressed way to do this? Needless to say, this becomes cumbersome when there are a lot of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
print (df_old.melt('year', value_name='val', var_name='col'))
   year col  val
0  2005   A    4
1  2006   A    5
2  2007   A    7
3  2005   B    3
4  2006   B    3
5  2007   B    9
6  2005   C    1
7  2006   C    7
8  2007   C    6
```

and for reorder columns [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df=df_old.melt('year',value_name='val', var_name='col').reindex(columns=['col','val','year'])
print (df)
  col  val  year
0   A    4  2005
1   A    5  2006
2   A    7  2007
3   B    3  2005
4   B    3  2006
5   B    9  2007
6   C    1  2005
7   C    7  2006
8   C    6  2007
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent. That was almost too easy :) Thank you! I will accept in 12 minutes :)

Comment: Is important ordering of columns?

Comment: Not really. But feel free to append your answer to show how I could rearrange the columns.